# when do the stargate Atlantis seasons take place in SG-1

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1, stargate-atlantis

I'm going to start a Stargate marathon where I watch all of SG-1 and Atlantis. I know the 2 series take place roughly in the same timeframe but I am wondering at what points in SG-1 do each seasons of Atlantis takes place.

While I am only asking about when each season of Atlantis takes place in regards to SG-1 if there are key mid-season moments in Atlantis that should be seen before a particular point in SG-1 (ie. the Replicators beginning their attack on the Wraith) then I am interested in these as well.

Comment: @keen's answer seems to cover this question quite closely